Setting up tensorflow GPU support in CONDA environment
I am trying to setup ML machine on my gaming desktop with RTX 3060 GPU, using ANACONDA and JUPYTERLAB. As shown in below logs, I have installed latest version of tensorflow and respective dependencies of CUDA toolkit, CUDA 12.3 and so on.
When I try to execute, print command, GPU devices are not getting detected. Eventhough they are visible via nvidia-smi command. Any help in resolving this issue would be of great help.
(tf-gpu) cf@gpu01:~$ conda list tensorflow
# packages in environment at /home/cf/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                2.16.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.36.0                   pypi_0    pypi
(tf-gpu) cf@gpu01:~$
(tf-gpu) cf@gpu01:~$ conda list cuda
# packages in environment at /home/cf/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12    12.3.101                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12     12.3.107                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12    12.3.107                 pypi_0    pypi
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12  12.3.101                 pypi_0    pypi
(tf-gpu) cf@gpu01:~$
(tf-gpu) cf@gpu01:~$
(tf-gpu) cf@gpu01:~$ nvidia-smi
Tue Apr  9 16:28:30 2024
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.23.06              Driver Version: 545.23.06    CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060        On  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   30C    P8              13W / 170W |    117MiB / 12288MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1352      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          105MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1442      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          5MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
(tf-gpu) cf@gpu01:~$
(tf-gpu) cf@gpu01:~$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))"
2024-04-09 16:28:36.890776: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-04-09 16:28:36.915935: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-04-09 16:28:37.295171: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-04-09 16:28:37.542828: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-04-09 16:28:37.563043: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
0
(tf-gpu) cf@gpu01:~$


It seems like TensorFlow is unable to detect your GPU,Ensure that the CUDA version installed (12.3 in your case) matches the version supported by TensorFlow (2.16.1). TensorFlow has specific CUDA and cuDNN version requirements for GPU support. Sometimes, a mismatch can prevent GPU detection.Confirm that TensorFlow was installed with GPU support. You can reinstall TensorFlow with GPU support using pip install** tensorflow-gpu==2.16.1**.Run the following Python code to check if TensorFlow can detect your GPU:

import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

Thanks for the reply @PriyaT. Its been a while and I have followed different approach to install ANACONDA and TF-GPU. This time after installing the nvidia driver I am just installing tensorflow-gpu variant.
